Why are Apache RewriteMap paths no longer being treated as absolute paths?
I use RewriteMap with the prg:<program> in Apache (v2.4.41 Ubuntu) to rewrite some requests. I've used this for some time and my rewrite program has returned absolute paths to the final file, and this has worked great until recently.
For some reason my server is adding a base path to my absolute path I am returning, and it seems to depend on which of my virtual hosts it thinks is being accessed.
So I have one rewrite where it's adding in the path to another host that I don't believe I'm asking for. My virtual domains are all inside of /WWW/vhosts/<domain>, and for this example I'm returning /WWW/vhosts/domainA/my/path/to/file and it's turning it into /WWW/vhosts/domainB/WWW/vhosts/domainsA/my/path/to/file.
What is the best way to figure out where and how Apache is adding to this path?  I thought that once RewriteMap was called and returned a path, that was it.

RewriteMap defines a lookup table which is subsequently accessed using ${ MapName : LookupKey } type substitution strings. How are you using the substitution string? Is it within a per-directory context?

@RichardSmith I'm not using the lookup table, I'm using the 'prg:' option for an external program.
